# Pandas outputs and dtypes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a set of data which I found the df.max().abs() and df.min().abs() for using python pandas (see below).

```
MaxCredit = update_balance2.max().abs()
MaxDebit = update_balance2.min().abs()
```

This gives the output:

```
balance    18389
dtype: int64
balance    18115
dtype: int64
```

However, I'd now like to find which of the two is the minimum value. How do you do this? I think the dtypes are stopping me some how. Does a new dataframe containing the two new values need to be created?

Comment: `min(MaxCredit,MaxDebit)` ? maybe?

Comment: @JoranBeasley Unfortunately I get the error: ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Comment: @JoranBeasley It ran with `min((MaxCredit) & (MaxDebit))` however, it returns 18113 ?!?!?1

Comment: then that must be one of the two options ... but im not exactly sure that min/max is actually doing what you expect ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you probably just need to select the column

```
MaxCredit = update_balance2.max().abs()
MaxDebit = update_balance2.min().abs()

min(MaxCredit['balance'],MaxDebit['balance'])
```

you could also do

```
 details = update_balance2.describe()
 min(details['balance']['max'],details['balance']['min'])
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Worked a treat, What about if I had a corresponding index to the values which are lettered A-M. I have set them as the index. How do I print the value of said index for the min() as aforementioned?